# how to create mbed project with os2?

Tags: operating-system, mbed

Although creation of a project with mbed os 5 works fine using 
    mbed new nameOfProgramOs5
creation of a project with mbed os 2 via 
    mbed new nameOfProgramOs2 --mbedlib 
causes a problem: 
First of all, the command does not terminate. 
ctrl-c unveils

```
[mbed] Working path "C:\Users\ere\Desktop\Software\MBed" (directory)
[mbed] Program path "C:\Users\ere\Desktop\Software\MBed"
[mbed] Creating new program "newWithMbedLib2" (git)
[mbed] Adding library "mbed" from "https://mbed.org/users/mbed_official/code/mbed/builds" at branch/tag "tip"
[mbed] Unpacking library build "3a7713b1edbc" in "C:\Users\ere\Desktop\Software\MBed\newWithMbedLib2\mbed"
[mbed] ERROR: An error occurred while unpacking library archive ".bld\.rev-3a7713b1edbc.zip" in "C:\Users\ere\Desktop\Software\MBed\newWithMbedLib2\mbed"
```

If i go into the directory i can see that a lot of sub directories are created 
one for each target. 
So may look not so bad. 
Could you help or at least contribute your own experience?

Is there a point to use still mbed os 2?

Answer (score 0):

`mbed new mbed-classic-program --mbedlib` works for me. It downloads the mbed 2.0 SDK. My mbed-cli version is 1.8.2.

Some boards only support OS 2. I still use OS 2 sometimes.